# Unable to locate the Android SDK

Tags: android, flutter, android-sdk-tools, flutter-layout, flutter-test

I already had [Android Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Studio) and the Android SDK installed. I later added Flutter and the Flutter SDK. Here is my problem: When I run

```
flutter doctor
```

It shows,

[image]

that I do not have the Android SDK installed.

Comment: Did you add $ANDROID_HOME to the path?

Comment: Which directory contains the Android SDK?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can configure the Android SDK for your project using

```
flutter config --android-sdk /path/to/android/sdk
```

The `PATH` variable also should contain the SDK, like

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/opt/android-sdk/emulator:/usr/local/opt/android-sdk/build-tools/26.0.1:/usr/local/opt/android-sdk/platform-tools:/usr/local/opt/android-sdk/tools
```

`/usr/local/opt/android-sdk` and `26.0.1` might not match your system. That's just an example.

Answer (score 13):

#### Step-by-step guidance for Windows with pictures

Step 1.

[image: Some screenshot]

If you see this error, it means Flutter does not locate your Android SDK.

There are two folders containing all files of the "Android SDK". They are "Platform" and "Platform Tools":

[image: Some screenshot]

Those folders are located in my computer *here*:

C:\Users\ZohaibSaleem\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

(My name is Zohaib Saleem, and you should replace my username folder name with your computer username.)

Step 2

Type "Env" in the search bar of Windows

[image: Some screenshot]

Click on *"System Variable Environment"*

[image: Some screenshot]

Click on *"Advanced and Environment Variable"*

[image: Some screenshot]

Go to *System Variable* → *Path* → *Edit*:

[image: Some screenshot]

Now paste the path of both folder "platform" and "platform-tools", respectively.

In my case, the paths are:

C:\Users\ZohaibSaleem\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms 
C:\Users\ZohaibSaleem\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools

After adding the path to your *System* variable it looks like:

[image: Some screenshot]

Click <kbd>OK</kbd>

Restart PowerShell and again *run* the command "flutter doctor".

Now, the Android SDK problem is resolved, but you faced another problem:

[image: Some screenshot]

To resolve this issue, just run the command

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

And accept all with "Y". At the end, after typing multiple 'Y's, again run 'flutter doctor' and *all* is set!

[image: Some screenshot]

Comment: please I have found the following error when I followed your steps: 

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    X Android SDK file not found: C:\Users\Abdesslem\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-32\android.jar.

Answer (score 5):

flutter config --android-sdk /your path

example

flutter config --android-sdk /root/Android/Sdk

Tools > SDK Manager > Android SDK

[images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auBlp.png)

Answer (score 2):

Locate the Android SDK folder (e.g., *D:\SDK*).

Add **platforms** (*D:\SDK\platforms*) and **platform-tools** (*D:\SDK\platform-tools*) to the PATH variable.

Run *flutter doctor*. It should not show any errors or warnings.

Comment: On [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows), presumably?

Comment: @PeterMortensen yes

Answer (score 0):

For this issue you have to add three variables to the Path in the:

1. `C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\platforms`  // The path to
   platform
2. `C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\platform-tools`  //
   The path to platform-tool
3. `C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\emulator`  // The path to
   emulator

Comment: this solution is for ANDROID_HOME ??

Comment: On [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows), presumably?