# How to build a flutter environment

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter, and I'm trying to build a flutter environment on windows 11, but when I type flutter doctor even though I have android studio, I get an error like the one below. I would appreciate it if someone could tell me what's going on!

```html
PS C:\> flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.376], locale ja-JP)
[✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    ✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.
      Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for detailed instructions).
      If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, please use
      `flutter config --android-sdk` to update to that location.

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[!] Android Studio
    ✗ android-studio-dir = C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    ✗ Unable to find bundled Java version.
[✓] VS Code (version 1.62.3)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
```

Comment: Where did you install the android studio? Because its clearly stated over there that it should be in program files

Answer (score 0):

Brother PLz Apply All these instructions Given in the Link below, Your problem will be solved.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52014476/unable-to-locate-the-android-sdk/52018999#52018999](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52014476/unable-to-locate-the-android-sdk/52018999#52018999a)

Comment: thank you so much! I solved it!!