# Flutter error: Unable to locate Android SDK

Tags: flutter, android-sdk-manager

I know that there are a ton of solutions on Stack Overflow for this issue but none of them is working for me.

I downloaded the Android SDK using Homebrew and set the path to the SDK using this command: `flutter config --android-sdk /usr/local/Caskroom/android-sdk` and I got this output:

```
Setting "android-sdk" value to "/usr/local/Caskroom/android-sdk".
You may need to restart any open editors for them to read new settings.
```

Now, when I run `flutter doctor --android-licenses`, I get this error:

```
Unable to locate Android SDK.
```

I've tried almost all the solutions on Stack Overflow. What can I try next?

Comment: just restart terminal and try again this command. sometimes editors require to be retstart or you can check this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49175231/flutter-does-not-find-android-sdk

Comment: please chek this links too and let me know if helps.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52014476/unable-to-locate-the-android-sdk.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fix-unable-to-locate-adb-within-sdk-in-android-studio/

Comment: @Vishal_VE hey, no luck :/ none of them work